# How do I get stereo output on Asus Xonar DGX in Linux?

Tags: rhel, audio, asus

How do I setup my *Asus Xonar DGX* to run 4.0 sound in Linux?  I get mono front and mono rear when I try.  I used `alsamixer` to set *Analog Output* to *Multichannel*.

When I run:

```
speaker-test -Dplug:surround40:DGX -t wav -c 4
```

It plays "Front Left", "Front Right" out of **both** speakers of headphones connected to the green headphone port on the back of the card.  Then it plays "Rear Left", "Rear Right" out of both speakers of headphones connected to the black surround port on the back of the card.  What do I need to do in order to get the channels separated?

NOTE: I'm running Kernel 4.1.12 that comes with Oracle Linux 7.5 (think RHEL 7.5).

NOTE: When I run the following with the same headphones connected to the green speaker out of the onboard sound card, "Left Front" is heard only on the left, then "Right Front" is heard only on the right.

```
speaker-test -Dplug:surround40:Intel -t wav -c 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The jacks on the Asus Zonar DGX card do not handle the Tip, Ring, Ring, Sleeve (TRRS) connector.  Works when using standard TRS cables.